# Consuming web service without ajax doesn't return all data

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, web-services, wcf

I have a problem went i consume the web service with ajax, it dont bring all the date especific the data consulting the database, but went i test the web service in the test mode it work fine, here is my code, what could be the problem?

this is my webservice code

```
  [WebMethod] 

    public string GetName(String name)
    {

        var RegisteredUsers = new List<Person>();
        String nombre = "";
        String enStock = "";
        int id = 1;
        if (Connect())
        { 

            Items oItem = (SAPbobsCOM.Items)oCompany.GetBusinessObject(BoObjectTypes.oItems);

            if (oItem.GetByKey(name))
            {
               nombre = oItem.ItemName;
                enStock = oItem.QuantityOnStock.ToString();
                id = 3;

            }
            id = 0;
        }
        var json = "";


        RegisteredUsers.Add(new Person() { PersonID = id, Name = nombre, stock = name });

        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        json = serializer.Serialize(RegisteredUsers);
        return json;
    }
```

this is the image of the result of the web service in the normal test
the result is correct it brings me all the data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qoz4.png)

but went i make the test on ajax it dont bring me all the data, what could be the problem?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AU8cX.png)

this is my web config code:

```
 <configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpRuntime/>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    </httpModules>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"/>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

this is my AJAX HTML CODE

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js1/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">



var dataString = 'name="1000066"';

                  $.ajax({
                          type: "POST",
                          url: "WebService1.asmx/GetName",
                          data: dataString,
                          success: function(data) { 

                               console.log(data);
                            },
                            error: function(xhr, status, error) {

                                                     alert(error);
                                                     alert(status);


                            },
                            complete: function(xData, status) {



                                $('#txt').html($(xData.responseXML).text()); // result
                            }

                        });




   </script>




  </head>

  <body>
   1000066
   <div id="resultado_json"></div>
   <div id="txt"></div>

   <form target="_blank" action='http://190.185.126.6:8092/WebService1.asmx/GetName' method="POST">                      

                          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" frame="box" bordercolor="#dcdcdc" rules="none" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                          <tr>
    <td class="frmHeader" background="#dcdcdc" style="border-right: 2px solid white;">Parameter</td>
    <td class="frmHeader" background="#dcdcdc">Value</td>
</tr>


                          <tr>
                            <td class="frmText" style="color: #000000; font-weight: normal;">name:</td>
                            <td><input class="frmInput" type="text" size="50" name="name"></td>
                          </tr>

                        <tr>
                          <td></td>
                          <td align="right"> <input type="submit" value="Invoke" class="button"></td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>


                    </form>



  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The function looks like it will only return a basic string? Are you expecting something more?

Comment: just a basic json string, but in the ajax it dont bring the name data, but it work find in with a post form. here you can test it http://190.185.126.6:8092/WebService1.asmx http://190.185.126.6:8092/index.html

Comment: You are expecting an individual "user" as a parameter, what's the point of the list then? You are serializing a list of users when really you should serialize just the single "Person". I would create an instance of the person, and then return it to your HTML via AJAX. See if it works like that. You can also do your $.ajax() call with the success:function(Data){ call back and do a console.log(data); to see what you get back.

Comment: i just add it, but send me the same date, could it be a configuracion in the web config that disbled the ajax objects call?

Comment: Can you post your HTML/AJAX code ?

Comment: i post my HTML/AJAX code up!!